# Search combo box dropdown list based on user input

Tags: vb.net, string, search, filter, combobox

I have a combo box with list items :

ABC
BAC
DEE

How can I have the list suggest based on input. e.g If user types A then it should show:
ABC
BAC
because they all contain the string character A.

Comment: Winforms? WPF? Asp.net MVC? Asp.net webforms?

Comment: I am doing with Winforms

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim AList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    ' Iterate through all the items in the combobox.
    For Each item As Object In ComboBox1.Items
        ' If the current item contains A then add to the list.
        If item.ToString.Contains("A") Then
            AList.Add(item.ToString)
        End If
    Next
```

Or you can do it via LINQ, which is basically the same :

```
    Dim AList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    Dim query = From item In ComboBox1.Items
                Where item.ToString.Contains("A")
                Select item

    For Each item in query
        AList.Add(item.ToString)
    Next
```

Comment: I tried your solution but my dropdown list, which has in it ABC,BAC and DEE do not suggest ABC and BAC as I type in A in the textbox. Since ABC and BAc contain A, I will like my dropdown to suggest only these 2 out of the 3 from the list when I type A. Thanks!

Comment: That can't be. Are you sure you put the code in the correct place? If you want the dropdown to suggest the items when you type in the text box, you need to make sure you put the code in the `TextChange` event of that text box, and of course not adding to the list in the example, but rather to the dropdown itself.

Comment: Yes! I have it on the TextChange event. When you say to add it to the dropdown itself, what do you mean?

Comment: Where you want those items to be displayed? At the moment, the code just "stores" them in an internal `List(Of String)`. Any way, the code works just fine for me.

Comment: I want them to be displayed as suggestions for the dropdown when I type A